# Can't deploy on device (Android MarshMallow Asus Zenfone 3)

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have a weird problem.

It happens on any xamarin project (Xamarin forms project in my case). I can run it on my Android api 22 (Samsung Core prime) and on a simulator but I cannot deploy it on my Android api 23 (Asus Zenfone 3). I get Index was outside the bounds of the array in the error panel. I tried on my mac and on my pc.
If I remember well, I was able to deploy on my Zenfone before an update. After that, there is no way

This is what I get in the output panel :

```
[E:]:                     
Deployment failed System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.    
at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidInstalledPackage..ctor(String value)    
at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.ParseLastResortPackageList(String output)    
at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.<>c__DisplayClass65_0.<GetPackagesLastResort>b__0(Task`1 t)    
at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()    
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

In the diagnostic panel, I have among other (maybe) normal things :

```
-- End Broadcast --
[D:RunShellCommand]:   GBAXGY16K66457B cat /data/system/packages.xml
-- Start GetPackages - 04/15/2017 23:34:34 (14.1293ms) --
[INPUT] cat /data/system/packages.xml
[OUTPUT]
/system/bin/sh: cat: /data/system/packages.xml: **Permission denied**
-- End GetPackages --
[D:RunShellCommand]:   GBAXGY16K66457B cat /dbdata/system/packages.xml
-- Start GetPackages - 04/15/2017 23:34:34 (14.5395ms) --
[INPUT] cat /dbdata/system/packages.xml
[OUTPUT]
/system/bin/sh: cat: /dbdata/system/packages.xml: **No such file or directory**
-- End GetPackages --
```

Rooting my phone is not an option I would like to consider. I would prefer sending it back and buy another one if there is no option.
Is it a Xamarin bug? Can I solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: [runtime permission](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Comment: Thanks but I don't have `permission denied` at runtime but when I deploy the app on the phone. As a consequence, I don't even have the app icon on my phone and I can't launch it.

Comment: You did have it installed on this phone at one point? See if there is any 'app management' in you Settings of the phone and see if your app is still in that list. Some Android versions do not delete all of the app by just deleting the icon

Comment: The app was never installed on the phone. I reset the phone and I still have the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Somebody answered my question on another forum. I share it here.
It looks like that this is a problem related to another app installed on the device. Auto-start Manager blocks the Mono Shared Runtime.
Open the setting and disable all possible blocks.
Now it should work

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Go to Mobile Manager ->

Settings Menu ->

Disable option: Automatically deny automatic application startup.

good luck!